# WPF Combobox - DataBind Empty Space Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple combobox bound to a List where A has a property Key and a property Value.

The combobox binds fine and works except for one flaw. It has a large empty space at the bottom where there are no items (i.e they don't get highlighted on hover or any such thing, there are no extra items, it is just that there is an empty space). How can I get rid of it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yN9r.jpg

[image: ComboBox Image]

Answer (score 0):

This is most-probably because of the template of the `ComboBox` under your current theme. Try changing Windows theme to Aero or Luna (seems like now you have it set to Classic).

If that's the issue, then there's a way to "fix" it by using a custom template, but then you break consistency from user's point of view. You'd need to take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the Template of combobox and reset the popup height acordingly. check below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Search for popup under the tempalte and add the minheight=0 into it.

Answer (score 0):

In my ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems..., if MyItems is a List, it will leave extra space. if MyItems is an ObservableCollection, the extra space goes away. This may due to a Microsoft bug that ItemsSource was not properly notify by MyItems change when it is a List object.